# How to refresh the data grid view when update? Window from C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to refresh the data grid view after the user insert some item to the database. And I tried to null the data source of the view and apply a new data source to it, but it didn't work.

Here is the flow of the system:

1. Click the add Item, then pop-up a `add-item form`
2. Input the product detail, then click the button to insert data
3. View update <-----Problem

[image]

In this part, there will have `two forms` and one `database claee`. They are `Form1` (the data view), `Add-item form` and the `database_function.cs`.

Here is my code on `database class`:

```
  public class database_function
{
   OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();


    public database_function()
    {
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\sys_db.accdb";
    }

    public void database_connect(String item_code, String des, String unit, double price)
    {
      Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        try
        {

            connect.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connect;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT into item (item_code, description, unit, price) values ('" + item_code + "', '" + des + "', '" + unit + "', " + price + ")";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connect.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Source);
            connect.Close();
        }
       f1.refresh_dataGridView();
    }



    //return the dataGridView to form 1, and show the database data on it.
    public DataTable get_view()
    {
        connect.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connect;
        string query = "Select item_code, description, unit, price from item";
        command.CommandText = query;

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        connect.Close();
        Debug.WriteLine("return dataTable");
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Here is the code on `form1`:
       //Get the data source when the form1 is loading
       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = df.get_view();
        }

```
   //Refresh the view
   public void refresh_dataGridView()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = df.get_view();
        Debug.WriteLine("refuesh");
    }
```

Here is the `add-item. form`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Get textfield data....

        //If user doesn't input the item data, show the error message. Else, update to database.
        if (error == true)
        {
            error_msg_form emf = new error_msg_form();
            emf.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            database_function df = new database_function();
             df.database_connect(item_code_tb.Text, des_tb.Text, unit_tb.Text, Convert.ToDouble(unit_price_tb.Text));
            //f1.refresh_dataGridView();
        }
    }
```

However, I debug log will show the `refresh`, that mean it can run in the `refresh_dataGridView()`. But it cannot refresh the view.

What is the problem is it? Or there have another way to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: `database_connect` method create new instance of `Form1`. You need update `datagridview` in already existed instance

Comment: `df.get_view()` is OK when you debug?

Comment: The `database_connect()` is created in another form which is the place for insert data. And the `gridView` is on another form.

Comment: Then you need pass reference of form where dataGridView is to the form where you adding row

Comment: Can you show code how you create and show form for inserting new row in database?

Comment: Yes, I tried to print out something. It shows that is work.

Comment: @Capslock10 Can you place the code from where you are calling the `database_connect` method?

Comment: I updated the code now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Capslock10, please have a look at my answer below and try the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `database_connect` method, pass the form reference as below with `this`,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Get textfield data....

    //If user doesn't input the item data, show the error message. Else, update to database.
    if (error == true)
    {
        error_msg_form emf = new error_msg_form();
        emf.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        //Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        database_function df = new database_function();
         df.database_connect(this, item_code_tb.Text, des_tb.Text, unit_tb.Text, Convert.ToDouble(unit_price_tb.Text));
        //f1.refresh_dataGridView();
    }
}
```

Then, add the parameter `Form1 form1` in the method as below and call `form1.refresh_dataGridView()` using the same reference.

```
public void database_connect(Form1 form1, String item_code, String des, String unit, double price)
    {
      //Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        try
        {

            connect.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connect;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT into item (item_code, description, unit, price) values ('" + item_code + "', '" + des + "', '" + unit + "', " + price + ")";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connect.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Source);
            connect.Close();
        }
       form1.refresh_dataGridView();
    }
```

Also, change the code as below to refresh the data grid view,

```
public void refresh_dataGridView()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = typeof(List);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = df.get_view();
        Debug.WriteLine("refuesh");
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the updated code where you are calling something like, `database_function.database_connect(this` ?

Comment: @Capslock10, I have updated the `refresh_dataGridView` method above. Please try the same. If it does not work then place the `database_function.database_connect(this` piece of code

Comment: @Capslock10, you didn't follow as I told you. I have updated the code above and follow exactly the same with all the three methods there in my answer. You should not create an instance with `Form1 f1 = new Form1()` which will create a new form and won't update your current form. Instead use `this` as I did above

Comment: You just copy paste my code above, will work 100% if you do it in a right way :-)

Comment: okay, its easy anyway. I hope you open another form from `form1`

Comment: Post the code to open this form in form1 and the constructor code of the second form. I will modify both the code. Its such easy :-)

Comment: I add passed the `Form1` to another form, and it work now! thanks a lot!

Comment: @Capslock10 great :-)

Answer (score 2):

You better refactor your code and separate database access code into separate class file. then you can call those functions from other classes, forms etc..

In your Form just after insert item method you can set the gridview data source, for example:

```
database_function df = new database_function();
df.InsertItem("sdfsdf", "Description", "KG", 5);
//load data again
dataGridView1.DataSource = df.get_view();
```

you need two methods, one for insert and one for get details

```
public class database_function
{
     public void InsertItem(String item_code, String des, String unit, double price)
        {
           //Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            try
            {
                connect.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connect;
                command.CommandText = "INSERT into item (item_code, description, unit, price) values ('" + item_code + "', '" + des + "', '" + unit + "', " + price + ")";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connect.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Source);
                connect.Close();
            }
         //f1.refresh_dataGridView();
        }

 public DataTable get_view()
    {
        connect.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connect;
        string query = "Select item_code, description, unit, price from item";
        command.CommandText = query;

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        connect.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

}

Comment: OP's problem is `Insert` method and `update` method is on different forms

Comment: @Fabio Yes, that is because of creating new form on insert function. What I'm suggesting is refactoring code and let the UI do the data source settings while db related functions handled in separate methods in another class.

Comment: Even if he move Db logic to dedicated class - main problem is that inserting row happens in the another form. And OP need somehow notify main form about successful insertion and update datagridview

Comment: It can insert the data, but the view will not update. The view only will update when I open the application again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used for mine:

```
    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (GlobalVariables.bReload == false) {
            Activated -= Form1_Activated;
            GlobalVariables.bReload = true;
            dgv1.DataSource = "my datasource"
            dgv1.Refresh();
            Activated += Form1_Activated;
        }
    }
```

In my case I wanted to trigger the update it after I made a modification on a subform and came back to the main form where my datagridview was located. I used a boolean type global variable to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you close "AddItem" form when item have been inserted to the database.
My suggestion to make notification about successful insertion more clearer without passing references and exposing form's control by making it public

Change you `database_connect` method to return `true/false` based on result of query

```
public void database_connect(String item_code, String des, String unit, double price)
{
    try
    {
        connect.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connect;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT into item (item_code, description, unit, price) values ('" + item_code + "', '" + des + "', '" + unit + "', " + price + ")";
        int insertedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return insertedRows > 0;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Source);
    }
    finally
    {
        connect.Close();
    }

    // false will be returned if exception will be thrown
    return false;
}
```

Then in the `AddItem` form set `Form.DialogResult` property to `Ok` if item was added successfully.

```
public class AddNewItemForm : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (error == true)
        {
            error_msg_form emf = new error_msg_form();
            emf.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            database_function df = new database_function();
            bool isAdded = df.database_connect(item_code_tb.Text,
                                               des_tb.Text, 
                                               unit_tb.Text,
                                               Convert.ToDouble(unit_price_tb.Text));

            if(isAdded)
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok;
            }
        }
    }             
}
```

Then in the Main form use `ShowDialog` method to get result about successful insertion.

```
public class MainForm: Form
{
    private void ButtonAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(var addItemForm = new AddNewItemForm())
        {
            if(addItemForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
            {
                // here you can update your DataGridView
                this.DataGridView.DataSource = df.get_view();
            }
        }
    }           
}
```